# Database crash after using proguard Android

Tags: android, database, crash, proguard

My application runs fine in debug mode, but crashes after proguard is enabled and signed apk is generated:

I am using android studio 1.5 for building apk.

Please find crash logs below:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.carwale.autobiz/com.carwale.autobiz.activities.ActivityDashboardDrawer}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: duplicate column name: a (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TC_CARCONDITION (_id integer primary key autoincrement,A TEXT,B TEXT,C TEXT,D TEXT,E TEXT,F TEXT,G TEXT,H TEXT,I TEXT,J TEXT,K TEXT,L TEXT,M TEXT,N TEXT,O TEXT,P TEXT,Q TEXT,R TEXT,S TEXT,T TEXT,U TEXT,a TEXT,b TEXT,c TEXT,d TEXT,e TEXT,f TEXT,g TEXT,h TEXT,i TEXT,j TEXT,k TEXT,l TEXT,m TEXT,n TEXT,o TEXT,p TEXT,q TEXT,r TEXT,s TEXT,t TEXT,u TEXT,v TEXT,w TEXT,x TEXT,y TEXT,z TEXT);
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2303)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:147)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5234)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704)
                                                    Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: duplicate column name: a (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TC_CARCONDITION (_id integer primary key autoincrement,A TEXT,B TEXT,C TEXT,D TEXT,E TEXT,F TEXT,G TEXT,H TEXT,I TEXT,J TEXT,K TEXT,L TEXT,M TEXT,N TEXT,O TEXT,P TEXT,Q TEXT,R TEXT,S TEXT,T TEXT,U TEXT,a TEXT,b TEXT,c TEXT,d TEXT,e TEXT,f TEXT,g TEXT,h TEXT,i TEXT,j TEXT,k TEXT,l TEXT,m TEXT,n TEXT,o TEXT,p TEXT,q TEXT,r TEXT,s TEXT,t TEXT,u TEXT,v TEXT,w TEXT,x TEXT,y TEXT,z TEXT);
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1674)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1605)
                                                       at com.carwale.localdatautils.l.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
                                                       at com.carwale.localdatautils.s.e(Unknown Source)
                                                       at com.carwale.localdatautils.d.d(Unknown Source)
                                                       at com.carwale.autobiz.activities.at.a(Unknown Source)
                                                       at com.carwale.autobiz.activities.at.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                       at com.carwale.autobiz.activities.ActivityDashboardDrawer.v(Unknown Source)
                                                       at com.carwale.autobiz.activities.ActivityDashboardDrawer.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5984)
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2256)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:147) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5234) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704) 


   04-20 08:35:14.326 915-1810/? E/ActivityManager: Invalid thumbnail dimensions: 0x0
```

Please find below my proguard-rules file:

```
-dontwarn org.apache.**
-dontwarn android.net.**
-dontwarn com.alexvasilkov.**
-dontwarn android.content.**
-dontwarn android.graphics.**
-dontwarn android.util.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.**
-dontwarn android.view.**
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLite isn't case sensitive.  So A and a are the same name.  You need to change the name of the column.

Comment: My actual column names are not those. I think proguard has changed them.

Comment: If your actual column names are those, it won't work.  You can't have two columns with the same name, and column names are case insensitive.

Comment: Also you can tell proguard didn't change them, because the changed names would be in the exception

Comment: It works in signed apk and withour proguard , also in debug mode

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense. Then yes, it looks like it did.